# Libre Office Calc Issue: Summarizing columns with too many rows

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm writing a script that reads data taken from a database. THe data is modified (de-duplicated) and put into a .csv file

I have a problem as I want to find the sum of a particular column in excel. My problem is that the sheer amount of data exceeds Calcs row limit.

My question is this, is there a Calc equation that can summarize an entire column without knowing how many rows there really are? (Past the limit?)
On that note, will the sum equation really return the total sum or just for the rows Calc is able to display?

Comment: "the maximum number of rows is 1,048,576". You really have more than this number of rows? [What is the maximum number of cells, rows, columns and sheets in a LibreOffice spreadsheet?](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Calc/022)

Comment: If so you would be better of doing the caculation **in the database**.

Comment: Agree with David the best option is to do this in your original database.  If you don't have access to the original database, the next best thing would be to connect Base to the CSV file and use a Base query to do your calculation.